# run script only if checkbox is true

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

I have the increaseline1 and increaseline2 on buttons. I would have it so the button only works if a checkbox is set to True

```
function modifyCell(cellName, increase, checkbox) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName)
  var toAdd =-1;
  if (increase) {
    toAdd = 1;
  }
   range.setValue(range.getValue() + toAdd);
 }

  function increaseline1() {
  modifyCell("Gus!G24!", true);


 function decreaseline1() {
  modifyCell("Gus!G24",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a button to work only if a checkbox is ticked. Use a conventional IF statement and test for a value of `true` (or `false`, as the need demands).

I have a checkbox in cell B2. The checkbox is ticked. This is the log for the following code:

> status = true
>
> Test#1: the checkbox is true/ticked
>
> Test#2: the checkbox is true/ticked

---

```
function so58276822() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "58276822";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var status = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  Logger.log("status = "+status)

  // test for false/unticked
  if (status === false){
    Logger.log("Test#1: the checkbox is false/unticked");
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("Test#1: the checkbox is true/ticked");
  }
  
  // test for true/ticked
  if (status === true){
    Logger.log("Test#2: the checkbox is true/ticked");
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("Test#2: the checkbox is false/unticked");    
  }
}
```